# Microsoft Edge JS Console - Is there a setting to have parenthesis, quotation mark... autocompletion?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I've tried searching internet but couldn't find anything with this browser's console. Does anybody have experience with this?
Functions or variables would autocomplete, but not parenthesis, brackets, quotation marks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can not only call it in the console, you can also get more relevant info through the name of the function and variable, or call more methods or get variables about this.

Something like this:

[image]

But if you need this feature, I recommand that you could send feedback to the relevant team, press `Alt + Shift + i` in Edge to edit your suggestion and send it.